# Vertical tabs with sub-tabs Bootstrap

Tags: html, tabs

I created vertical tabs with Bootstrap, currently the "home tab" is not showing the tabbed content, kind of buggy. Also, I'm having trouble creating sub tabs to each individual vertical navs. Is it easier to create sub tabs with jQuery?

HTML

```
          <nav class="navigation">
            <ul class="menu nav-menu">
             <div class="nav nav-tabs flex-column" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
               <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a class=" nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a></li>

               <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a class=" nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a></li>
               <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a class=" nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a></li>
               <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a class=" nav-link" id="nav-about-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-about" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-about" aria-selected="false">About</a></li>
             </div>
           </ul>
         </nav>
        </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
            <div class="tab-content py-3 px-3 px-sm-0" id="nav-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
              home
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
            profile
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
            contact
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-about" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-about-tab">
            about
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
```

Thanks!